# Chrome resets scroll position with css-grid and overflow:auto

Tags: css, google-chrome, overflow, grid-layout

I'm working on a page where a footer element is "stickied" to the bottom of a page (using good old `position: fixed` for compatibility), until the user scrolls far enough down for it to become `position: static`.

However, the moment `fixed` becomes `static`, chrome scrolls the parent div back to the top.

I made a codepen to illustrate.

https://codepen.io/Sulsay/pen/eVmmNZ

1. Drag it small enough for a scrollbar to appear;
2. Scroll down;
3. When the purple bar goes full-width (`position: fixed`), you'll notice Chrome automatically scrolls the `#content` div (with `overflow: auto`) back to the top.

I've reduced the pen to only contain the grid layout, and the `overflow: auto` on the `#content` div. It appears that Chrome doesn't like this combination. Removing `overflow: auto` eliminates the scroll issue, but also causes the header and the sidebar to scroll, which I don't want.

Other browsers show the expected behavior, which is to maintain scroll position and not jump back to the top.

Is this Chrome specific, and possibly a bug? Or am I missing something? I've searched SO and the chrome bug tracker, but to my surprise, nothing turned up.

Comment: I just ran into this as well. My situation is slightly different, but I have the same `display:grid` wrapper with a `overflow:auto` child. In my case, I don't have any `position:fixed`, but when I update the content of the scrollable div via javascript (React), it scrolls back to the top. Maybe any time the div gets re-flowed this happens? It does seem like a Chrome bug to me. Same code works fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

While browsing for other solutions for this bug, I found this hack-fix which has served me quite nicely: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49560943 (credit to [Chris Boon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2175571/chris-boon))

To summarize the fix, instead of using `auto` or `1fr` for your grid row height, use `minmax(1px, 1fr)`. This seems to force the browser to be more careful about calculating the height of the area and prevents the scroll jumping to the top or the bottom.

I've adapted the fix for your example pen:

https://codepen.io/a-type/pen/RJqJwL

This doesn't prevent the scroll height from changing when your footer goes from fixed to static, but that is expected behavior as the element moves in and out of the layout flow within your scrolling container. In my local Chrome (67.0.3396.62), though, it **does** prevent the scroll area from jumping back to 0.

Note that this hack-fix seems to have some adverse effects on performance, but I haven't measured it personally.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    const testSubject = document.getElementById("test-subject");
    const stylePosition = testSubject.style.position;
    testSubject.style.position = stylePosition === "fixed" ? "static" : "fixed";
  }, 500);
});
```

change pls

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    const testSubject = document.getElementById("test-subject");
    const stylePosition = testSubject.style.display;
    testSubject.style.display = stylePosition === "none" ? "inherit" : "none";
  }, 500);
});
```

Comment: no answer to the question. This makes the bar disappear and doesn´t make it static

Comment: window.addEventListener ("DOMContentLoaded", () => {document.getElementById ("test-subject"). style.position = 'static';}); bu ko d static makes

Answer (score 0):

Took me some time to find a proper solution, but got 1 you might can live with:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YeXqXd

instead of fixed and static I made it fixed and absolute.
Furthermore I added a

```
<div id="#contentwrapper">
```

and gave it:

```
 #contentwrapper{
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

If the sticky footer is the footer of the whole page (like in the example) you could also just make him fixed permanently and add a padding bottom to the #content, but if there follow other elements you might need the wrapper and relative/absolute.

EDIT: Forgot overflow: auto for the #contentwrapper

edited the codepen

Comment: This scrolls the entire page however, not just the content div. I'll probably end up using something with position:absolute, but I'm stumped as to why this causes trouble for chrome and not for any other grid-supporting browser.

Comment: Sorry , forgot the overflow auto on the wrapper. I fixed it with the codepen. You might need to change the "bottom" rule aswell with javscript, when changing the position. Sadly I can´t tell you why this occurs in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Chrome bug that as of this writing has not been addressed. The only work-around I know of is to not use scrollable elements inside css grid elements when the content/css might change via javascript.

Reference: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=833837