# container scrolls to top when children element height changes

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-grid

I came across a bit quirky behavior. At least it seems quirky to me.

You can check it out here: https://fiddle.jshell.net/mxmcd9Lw/8/show/

Mainly when a element's height changes its parent element scrolls automatically to the top (you need to scroll down a bit first). Seems like offset top is lost because of the repaint that is caused by a height change.

- structure is based on CSS Grid
- `body` overflow is set to hidden
- main container `.l-page` is set to 100vh
- scrolled container `.l-content`

```css
 body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.l-page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 'primary_bar primary_bar' 'sidebar notification' 'sidebar secondary_bar' 'sidebar content';
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 1280px;
  max-width: 1920px;
}

.l-notification {
  grid-area: notification;
}

.l-primary-bar {
  grid-area: primary_bar;
  z-index: 2;
}

.l-secondary-bar {
  grid-area: secondary_bar;
  z-index: 1;
}

.l-sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  width: 180px;
}

.l-content {
  grid-area: content;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

I tried:

- setting both `html` and `body` to overflow hidden
- setting both `html` and `body` `height`, `min-height` to 100% in different configuration
- https://abdus.co/blog/preventing-vh-jump-on-mobile-browsers/ (method 2)

but with no luck.

I am sure it has something to do with the fact that body is not scrollable and that main container's height is set to `100vh`.

**Note** On Chrome it jumps to the very top, on FF and Safari to the bottom.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Thx!**

Lukas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to happen most times when the grid-area is set to something dynamic and has overflow  - for example if you set `.l-page` to `grid-template-rows: repeat(4, auto)` the bug is still present, but in `grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 100px)` it is not.

I have found a work-around that works in Chrome. Setting `.l-page` to `grid-template-rows: auto auto auto minmax(1px, 1fr);` somehow keeps the scroll position as you would expect. I don't know why though.

Here's the modified fiddle:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/mxmcd9Lw/59/

Also, worth noting in Firefox Developer Edition v60 the bug appears to be fixed - your example works fine there. So I assume this is a known bug that will be resolved by browsers shortly.

Comment: Actually just tested sample code in FF58 on Mac and the bug doesn't appear, so looks like it's already been fixed in FF and OP is on an old version. In Safari 10.1.1 it scrolls to the top the same as Chrome Beta 66.

Comment: wow!
it freaking works :D
was driving our team crazy for quite a while.
good to know a work-around, and that's a quirk that is going to be addressed one day. hopefuly soon. THX a lot!

Comment: @ChrisBoon do you have a link to the Chrome bug report?

Comment: Nevermind, found the bug link: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=833837