# Why does Chrome 80 cause this grid-template-rows: auto problem

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-grid

Is anyone aware what is up with the latest Chrome 80 update?

Seems like

```css
grid-template-rows: auto
```

started taking up some space from now even when a given row is not present in the markup. Happens on Chrome 80+ only.

```css
.l-page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto minmax(1px, 1fr);
  /*  // 1px is needed because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49558290/container-scrolls-to-top-when-children-element-height-changes */
  grid-template-areas:
    'sidebar primary_bar'
    'sidebar notification'
    'sidebar content';
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.l-sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.l-notification {
  grid-area: notification;
}

.l-primary-bar {
  grid-area: primary_bar;
}

.l-content {
  grid-area: content;
}
```

```html
<div class="l-page">
  <div class="l-sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <!--<div class="l-notification"></div>
      <div class="l-primary-bar"></div>-->
  <div class="l-content">content</div>
</div>
```

See also: https://jsfiddle.net/ju4xvegf/

**Chrome 80**
[image]

**Firefox 72**
[image]

Comment: does `grid-template-rows:  minmax(0px, auto)  minmax(0px, auto)  minmax(1px, 1fr);` fixes it to the expected result ?

Comment: nope, it doesn't

Comment: Is there a reason why : `grid-template-rows: auto auto  1fr;`is not an option ? *because that works fine ;)*

Comment: I would vote for a bug, still with Chrome V79 so I cannot verify

Comment: @TemaniAfif If you want to update, 80 is out of beta and should get pushed to you if you visit the Chrome About page.

Comment: @G-Cyr I don't know why but the comments in the JSFiddle indicate `minmax(1px, 1fr)` is required due to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49558290/container-scrolls-to-top-when-children-element-height-changes) by the OP as well a while back.

Comment: @TylerH well, it's 2 years old, it's been many updates since ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr True, and the associated bug was [fixed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=833837) on Feb 2, 2019...

Comment: true that, need to unhack the thing, thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if it's a bug or something has changed in the CSS grid algorithm (need to revise the Spec) but you can simplify your logic like below:

```css
.l-page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto minmax(0, 1fr);
  height: 300px;
  margin:5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.l-sidebar {
  grid-row: span 3;
  grid-column:-3;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.l-primary-bar {
  order: 1;
}
.l-notification {
  order: 2;
}

.l-content {
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="l-page">
  <div class="l-sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="l-content">content</div>
</div>

<div class="l-page">
  <div class="l-sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="l-notification">notif</div>
  <div class="l-primary-bar">bar</div>
  <div class="l-content">content</div>
</div>

<div class="l-page">
  <div class="l-sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="l-notification">notif</div>
  <div class="l-content">content</div>
</div>

<div class="l-page">
  <div class="l-primary-bar">bar</div>
  <div class="l-notification">notif</div>
  <div class="l-sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="l-content">content</div>
</div>

<div class="l-page">
  <div class="l-primary-bar">bar</div>
  <div class="l-notification">notif</div>
  <div class="l-content">content</div>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE**

With your initial code, if you change `minmax(1px,1fr)` with only `1fr` it should work fine.

```css
.l-page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    'sidebar primary_bar'
    'sidebar notification'
    'sidebar content';
    height: 300px;
  margin:5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.l-sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.l-notification {
  grid-area: notification;
}

.l-primary-bar {
  grid-area: primary_bar;
}

.l-content {
  grid-area: content;
}
```

```html
<div class="l-page">
  <div class="l-sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="l-content">content</div>
</div>

<div class="l-page">
  <div class="l-sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="l-notification">notif</div>
  <div class="l-primary-bar">bar</div>
  <div class="l-content">content</div>
</div>

<div class="l-page">
  <div class="l-sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="l-notification">notif</div>
  <div class="l-content">content</div>
</div>

<div class="l-page">
  <div class="l-primary-bar">bar</div>
  <div class="l-notification">notif</div>
  <div class="l-sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="l-content">content</div>
</div>

<div class="l-page">
  <div class="l-primary-bar">bar</div>
  <div class="l-notification">notif</div>
  <div class="l-content">content</div>
</div>
```

It seems that the new version of chrome is resolving the `minmax(1px,1fr)` differently. You can try to increase the value of `1px` slowly and notice how the `minmax()` will make the row bigger.

Note that `1fr` is equivalent to `minmax(auto,1fr)` https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1777

Related question having a similar issue: [grid-template-columns in Chrome 80 inconsistently computed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60193734/8620333)

Comment: thx! I really like this simplification, but how would U go about a version with no sidebar and no extra modifying classes?

Comment: interesting ; ]
just to be safe I would do grid-row: -1/1; so grid-column must be equal to number of rows

Comment: @LukaGronko yes it would produce the same result in this case ;)

Comment: @LukaGronko no grid column must be set to -3 because we have one explicit column so to place our element before it we need to count 3 lines (-1 is the edge, -2 is the starting of the explicit column and -3 is a new line before)

Comment: awesome! and if I wanted to put a sidebar to the right side? https://d.pr/i/Ql8uB2 https://d.pr/i/l0PEZG

Comment: @LukaGronko you add `grid-auto-flow: dense;` to the grid container and you change -3 by 2 for the sidebar

Comment: one more question, does "order" create implicit line names?

Comment: @LukaGronko no, it simply define the order of the placement of the element. By explicitely specifying the order you can put the elements in any order in the code and you will always have the same result. With no order specified the HTML code will decide

Comment: this I get, one more issue though, it wont work if there are some extra rows inside l-page, like a third party <div> or <router-outlet> etc.

Comment: @LukaGronko make sure to give an order equal to at least 4 for any other element so any unexpected div will always be placed at the end.

Comment: @LukaGronko found another fix to your issue

Answer (score 0):

*NB: I'm distracted while writing this answer, and I haven't dived into CSS Grid in a while, so this is just my best guess as to what's going on.*

I think this is related to your named `grid-template-areas` as well, not just your `grid-template-rows` setting. You have the following named areas in your CSS:

```css
grid-template-areas:
    'sidebar primary_bar'
    'sidebar notification'
    'sidebar content';
```

But in your markup, you have two of those right-column divs commented out:

```html
<!--<div class="l-notification"></div>
    <div class="l-primary-bar"></div>-->
```

Firefox, and Chrome prior to v80, appear to have ignored `grid-template-areas` that are empty or don't exist in the markup, hence why you see `content` on the same row as `sidebar` at the top. However, it looks like Chrome v80 has decided that, since you have declared multiple rows via your `grid-template-areas` property, it should reserve at least one row of space, perhaps using the following logic:

"*collapse all empty rows into one row, then start rows with content on the next available row in the grid*"

rather than what Chrome 79 (and Firefox 72) does:

"*collapse all empty rows completely so that only rows with contents appear.*"

In short, you need to remove one of the named areas in your `grid-template-areas` property that you don't have markup for. I'll keep looking.

Comment: thank you for sharing your findings
well that was the cool part of this solution, as these two sections could appear in the markup or not

Comment: *it looks like Chrome v80 has decided that, since you have declared multiple rows via your grid-template-areas property, it should reserve at least one row of space, perhaps using the following logic:* --> even in Chrome 79, the area aren't but are empty. You can add grid-gap to notice this: https://jsfiddle.net/z6af1me9/ . It seems a bug for me

Comment: yes, they were there but were not taking any room, until now...

Comment: now I see the behavior and it's indeed intresting. If you play with grid-gap and you watch the grid it's even more surprising how it behaves.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yep, I did it with applying different background colors to each grid-area but grid-gap would probably be simpler.